# DynamoDB How to Setup "Reverse lookup GS"

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to figure out how to implement a reverse lookup GSI in DyamoDB.  I attended an amazing talk about DynamoDB at reInvent this year (https://youtu.be/HaEPXoXVf2k?t=2674).  Around 44 minutes into the talk the idea of a Reverse Lookup GSI is presented.  I can't figure out how to implement this in  Dynamo.

I want to add a single GSI to do a reverse lookup.

My current Scheme looks like:
[image]

I would like to be able to query on just the CXSK.   I'm planning on overloading the CXSK and would love to be able to do a query with a begins with for that key.

I'm not sure what I'm missing when I go to create the GSI.  I'm not sure what should go in the following fields. I'm also curious if it makes sense to have an overloaded Sort Key.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say this is your original table

```
| pk   |  sk   |  prop1     |   prop2 | ...
| a    |  b    |  xyz       |   abc
| a    |  c    |  lmn       |   opq
| b    |  x    |  rst       |   lme   
| b    |  b    |  tuv       |   opq
```

in the above table you can do queries like

`select * where pk = a` It will return row 1 and 2

`select * where pk = a and sk = b` it will return row 1

Now to do reverse lookup mean you want to aggregate data by some other field name. 
Let's say we want to do it by sk. To do this we will create a GSI with sk as partitionKey and pk as SortKey. And this view of table will look like

This will be your GSI1 table

```
| pk   |  sk   |  prop1     |   prop2 | ...
| b    |  a    |  xyz       |   abc
| c    |  a    |  lmn       |   opq
| x    |  b    |  rst       |   lme   
| b    |  b    |  tuv       |   opq
```

in the above table you can do queries like

`select * where pk = b` It will return row 1 and 4

`select * where pk = b and sk = a` it will return row 1

Considering the above description, in your case you should create GSI with pk as CXSK and sk as USERId

Comment: That makes sense.  I'm I only able to query on  = ,<,<= , > , >= , BETWEEN,BEGINS_WITH.  Is it ever possible to query using 'contains' or 'exists'? I assume that 'contains' and 'exists' is only used for filters.